# error 1053 when starting a service installed by install4j

Tags: windows, install4j

I am trying to make a bundled JBoss AS 7 into my exe, and install it as a service, so in the "Install a Service" action, I use [Other Service Executable], and give it the full path to standalone.bat so that it could execute it.

The service gets installed correctly, however when I try to start it , it gives me the error 1053

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control
>   request in a timely fashion

What it is that I could have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"standalone.bat" is not a service executable, so it cannot be started by the service manager. Either you have a 3rd party service executable for JBoss, or you can set up a generated service launcher in install4j that mimics the call made in standalone.bat.

Comment: Thank you @Ingo, I think I'll use the native connectors from [here](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10) and use install4j to execute service.bat.